# Writing $\sup$ and $\inf$ in unions

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Could someone please explain why the following hold for a set of a functions $f_n(x)$:

$$\{x : \sup f_n > c \} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{ x: f_n(x) > c \}$$
$$\{x: \inf f_n < c \} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{ x: f_n(x) < c \}$$

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\sup f_n (x) > c$, then there exists $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $f_n(x) > c$ (if not, then $f_n(x) \leq c, \forall n$, which implies $\sup f_n(x) \leq c$, contradiction). So we have:
$$\sup f_n(x) > c \Leftrightarrow \exists n \in \mathbb N: f_n(x) > c $$ 
Thus,
$$x \in \{\sup f_n > c \} \Leftrightarrow \exists n \in \mathbb N: x \in  \{f_n > c \} \Leftrightarrow x \in \cup_n\{f_n > c\}.$$
Similar for $\{\inf f_n < c \}$.

Comment: ok, so for $\{x: \inf f_n < c\}$ there exists a $n$ such that $f_n(x) < c$ else $f_n(x) \geq c$ but this is not a contradiction as $ inf f_n < c \leq f_n$

Comment: if $f_n(x) \geq c$, then $\inf f_n(x) \geq \inf c = c$.